# I cant use setTimeout and event.clientX in the same function without getting this error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, settimeout, cursor-position

I want to set an elements position equal to the position of the cursor every one second. But as soon as i include the setTimout attribute in the function it stops working and prints the following error in the log: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". 
I have tried to run the code without a timeout but then the page freeze. 
Here is the code that i can't get to work:

---

```js
function moveElement() {
    while (true) {
        x = event.clientX;
        y = event.clientY;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = x + " " + y; //This line is not important
        setTimeout(moveElement(), 1000);
        document.getElementById("test").style.color = "blue";
        document.getElementById("test").style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById("test").style.top = y + "px";
    }
};
```

Also i get this error when i try to run event.clientX outside a function: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined"

Can somebody see what is wrong with my code or just tell me another method to get it to work (no jQuery please)? Thank you.

/HamMan4Ever

Comment: `while(true)` do you realise you're killing your processor ?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `setTimeout` directly, it's because you're calling `moveElement()` within itself.  You need to pass a function reference to `setTimeout`, ie `setTimeout(moveElement, 1000)`.  As @Lauromine says though, `while(true)` without a way to break out of it is nonsensical.

Comment: @Lauromine Therefor i use the timeout. I don't know i'm pretty new at coding n' stuff

Comment: The `setTimeout()` function does not pause execution. It represents a request that a function be called at a specific time in the future.

Comment: @HamMan4Ever Doing a `while loop` with a condition which will always be true is like doing a `for loop` with Infinity as the limit. What's inside will be called again, and again, and again ...

Comment: The mousemove event is a recurring event. This means that when you move your mouse, the even will fire like a hundred times! A while loop isn't a good option here. Use a flag that says whether to update the position or not. Are you familiar with boolean variables?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Thank you @www139 . Yes i know a little about boolean. So what you say is that i shall make a function that will only be called when i move the mouse instead of just calling it contentiously?

Comment: I will update my answer with a detailed explanation about how the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example waits until the mouse has stopped moving and then waits a second, then applies the new position.
I can create another example that just updates the position every second although it might be a good idea to wait for the mouse to stop moving.

This code waits for a mousemove and then clears any existing timers that are running and then sets up a new one. It also captures and stores the information about the mouse move to be used later.
Since the mousemove event is a recurring event (it fires like a thousand times whenever you move the mouse) which is why whenever the mouse is moved, all timers are cleared to avoid having multiple timers set at the same time.

The end result of this code is that when you move the mouse, it will wait until you have stopped moving the mouse, waits one second, and then sets the divs coord.

Please let me know in the comments if there is anything else I can do for you.

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){//when the page loads
  //initialize all variables.
  var timer = false;
  var updateTracking = false;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){//when the mouse is moved.
    clearTimer();//clear the existing timer
    updateTracking = true;//set the flag so that the if statement knows the mouse has been moved.
    x = e.x;//get the X coord of the mouse move
    y = e.y;//get the Y coord of the mouse move
    setTimer();//set a timer for 1 second.
  });
  //the function that sets the timer.
  function setTimer(){
      //set the "timer" variable to a timer function
      timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(updateTracking == true){//if the mouse has been moved
          var elem = document.getElementById('theDiv');//get the element
          updateTracking = false;//reset the flag since the element has been updated
          elem.style.top = y+'px';//set the Y coord of the element
          elem.style.left = x+'px';//set the X coord of the element
        }
      },1000);
  }
  function clearTimer(){//cleat timer function; clears any existing timers
    window.clearTimeout(timer);//clear the timer  
  }
});
```

```css
#theDiv{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Here is another code snippet that shows you how the mousemove event functions. Just open your console and move the mouse...

```js
window.onload = function(){
  window.onmousemove = function(){
    console.log('the mouse was moved');
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
setTimeout(moveElement(), 1000);
```

Which should be:

```
setTimeout(moveElement, 1000);
```

Parentheses at the end of a function calls it immediately. So this function was just calling itself over and over. You want to pass a reference to the function that timeout should call after the specified time.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

You also should remove while(true) which will just loop forever. This is most likely why you received the above error. If you want to call this function every second just use setTimeout which will wait the amount of time specified and then call the function reference you passed it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
```

This happens because there is no event variable that exists. Usually an event is passed to a function that has been attached as a handler to some event.

Here is an example of attaching an event and using clientX/clientY in some way. Perhaps it will help you understand and expand on it to do whatever it is you are trying to do:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqpvkjd9/

HTML:

```
<div id="test">some text</div>
```

JS:

```
function moveElement (event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.style.color = "blue";
    test.style.left = x + "px";
    test.style.top = y + "px";
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

And lastly you should really declare x and y using var as I did above. Without var they are assumed to be global variables which is usually not good.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to **setTimeout** must be a function.  When you use code like `moveElement()` you are *calling* the function (again) instead of just providing a reference to it.  So I think you would be better of doing something like this:
`setTimeout(moveElement, 1000);`

The `while (true)` loop is causing your page to freeze because it is an eternal loop; It will run your code repeatedly, forever and doesn't give your browser time to breathe.  The poor thing.